# How does cuelang implement list appending?

Tags: cuelang

I am rendering a yaml file using cuelang and want to implement a list append, but I cannot get the correct result。

Below is my sample code test.cue

```
t: #input
uiSchema: {}
#input: {
    _stages: [{
        "id": 31,
        "jobs": [{
            "name": "echo",
            "stepType": "execute_shell",
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 32,
        "jobs": [{
            "name": "docker-build-push",
            "stepType": "docker_build_and_push",
        }]
    }]
}

    spec: {
        params: [{
                    name: "my-container"
            },...]
        workspaces: [
            {
                name: "git-credentials"
            },
        ]
    }

    for _, stage in t._stages for job in stage.jobs if job.stepType == "docker_build_and_push" {
        params: [ID=string]: {
                #appendContainer
                params: [...{
                        name: string
                }]
        }
        #appendContainer: params: params + [{
            name: "appened container"
        }, ...]
    }
```

Run the cuelang command

```
PS C:\> go run cuelang.org/go/cmd/cue eval   test.cue
```

Expect an output， I tried the cuelang + operator, but got nested [["name": 111]]

```
    params: [
      {
        name: "my-container"
      },
      {
        name: "appened container"
      },
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way I've found is to use Cue's `list` package and make use of the `Concat` function, which is used to combine two lists.
For instance, something like this:

```
import "list"

list1: ["foo", "bar"]
toBeAppended: "baz"

combinedList: list.Concat([list1, [toBeAppended]])
```

produces this output when `cue eval test.cue` is run:

```
list1: ["foo", "bar"]
toBeAppended: "baz"
combinedList: ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's without needing `import`

```
list1: ["foo", "bar"]
toBeAppended: "baz"

combinedList: list1 + [toBeAppended]
```

```bash
% cue eval test.cue
list1: ["foo", "bar"]
toBeAppended: "baz"
combinedList: ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

ref: https://cuetorials.com/deep-dives/closedness/#list-closedness